# Are these the same versions/distributions of mgo?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have found two places of the mongodb driver in Go

- http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2 and http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson
- http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo
  and http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson

Are they the same distribution and version of mongodb driver in Go?

Why are there two pathnames for the same package?

Which one of the two shall I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The package labix.org/v2/mgo was moved to gopkg.in/mgo.v2 according to 
 [a commit in the gopkg.in/mgo.v2 source](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/commit/d1fb2c3135adc0ef611f8700af3ea17b3385b6b7).

The author of mgo also created [gopkg.in](http://labix.org/gopkg.in). He moved several of his packages from his "vanity" path on labix.org to gopkg.in.

The source for labix.org/v2/mgo is at http://bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/mgo/v2/files/head:/. The most recent update is July 1, 2014.

The source for gopkg.in/mgo.v2 is at https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/tree/v2. This tree is a continuation of bazaar.launchpad.net/+branch/mgo/v2. The most recent update is June 9, 2016.

Use gopkg.in/mgo.v2.

Answer (score 1):

You can find more information [in the official page](http://labix.org/mgo). The page links

```
gopkg.in/mgo.v2
```

From what I can see, `labix.org/v2/mgo` is probably the version 1 of the driver, whereas `gopkg.in/mgo.v2` is the new version.

Go doesn't have traditional package distribution or versioning. Therefore, if you need a major refactoring and you want to break backward-compatibility, a common approach is to publish a different version at a different path.

I guess that's what happened here.

Comment: thanks. does `v2` in `labix.org/v2/mgo` mean version 2 or 1 of the driver?

Comment: I'm not sure. Actually, I've just noticed `gopkg.in` is actually a version-aware redirector. Hence, it's even possible that in reality `gopkg.in/mgo.v2` is an alias for the labix.org path. I'd use `gopkg.in/mgo.v2` in any case.